# How to disable iframe console.log in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, console.log

I am building an app that has a section that displays news. Every news item has a preview button, that displays the source of an iframe. All good, until I see that some news pages are `console.log` a lot. I have successfully turned off `console.log` for my app, but not for the iframe.
I have tried the following, but it's not working for my case:

```
const iFrameRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
    if(iFrameRef.current){
      const iframeWindow = iFrameRef.contentDocument;
      iframeWindow.console.log = function() { };
    }
  }, [iFrameRef]);

<iframe ref={iFrameRef} src={source} id="iFramePreview" />
```

What is the method to turn off console.log for an iframe?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want this? Seems better to just let the stuff log if it wants to.

Comment: I am building this app for work, there cannot be console.logs from news websites.

Comment: Curious as to why that would really matter, other than someone thinks it's a bad thing. No idea why it would *technically* be a bad reason. Is there a security concern or something? (Because if there is a legitimate, reason, then I would really like to know what it is, so I know when I might need to do something similar).

Comment: No, it's not a security issue, but it's the teams policy.